# How does the chai expect function work?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

From chai's api you've got code like this:

```
.exist

Asserts that the target is neither null nor undefined.

var foo = 'hi'
  , bar = null
  , baz;

expect(foo).to.exist;
expect(bar).to.not.exist;
expect(baz).to.not.exist;
```

How does that exist part work? The expect function returns an object, then there's simply a property lookup on the "to" object. That's simply a property evaluation though isn't it? The only thing that would make sense to me is if the exist property is a getter method.

What's the go?

Comment: It's a *getter property*.

Comment: Yeah, not used to using them a lot.

Comment: Well, `chai` embraces them. And you haven't had a look at `should`…

Comment: The fact that we are even discussing this question means chai is designed with too much magic.

Answer (score 5):

chai exposes an `use` method to access the `chai` export and it's `utils`.

This method can be used by third parties when [creating plugins](http://chaijs.com/guide/plugins/), but it's also used internally to load it's interface.

The implementation of this method is simple:

```
exports.use = function (fn) {
  if (!~used.indexOf(fn)) {
    fn(this, util);
    used.push(fn);
  }

  return this;
};
```

Internally it uses this to load (among other) the primary `Assertion prototype` and the core assertion functionality:

```
var assertion = require('./chai/assertion'); // primary Assertion prototype
exports.use(assertion); // load it

var core = require('./chai/core/assertions'); // core assertion functionality
exports.use(core); // load it
```

One of the methods that are exposed by the `Assertion prototype` is the `addProperty` method which allows you to add properties to said `prototype`.

Internally `chai` uses this method to add the core assertion functionality to the `Assertion prototype`. For instance, all language chains and assertion helpers (`exist`, `empty`, etc) are added this way.

Language chains:

```
[ 'to', 'be', 'been'
  , 'is', 'and', 'has', 'have'
  , 'with', 'that', 'which', 'at'
  , 'of', 'same' ].forEach(function (chain) {
    Assertion.addProperty(chain, function () {
      return this;
    });
  });
```

All this functionality becomes available when a specific interface gets loaded internally, for instance `expect`. When this interface is loaded, a new `Assertion prototype` will be instantiated whenever `expect` gets executed, which will contain all functionality:

```
// load expect interface
var expect = require('./chai/interface/expect'); // expect interface
exports.use(expect); // load it

// expect interface
module.exports = function (chai, util) {
  chai.expect = function (val, message) {
    return new chai.Assertion(val, message); // return new Assertion Object with all functionality
  };
};
```

As you can see the `expect` method accepts a `val` argument (and an optional `message` argument). When this method is called (for instance `expect(foo)`) a new `Assertion prototype` will be instantiated and returned, exposing all core functionality (allowing you to do `expect(foo).to.exist`).

The `Assertion Constructor` uses the `flag` `util` to set a flag value on the Object that maps to the passed in `val` argument.

```
  function Assertion (obj, msg, stack) {
    flag(this, 'ssfi', stack || arguments.callee);
    flag(this, 'object', obj); // the 'object' flag maps to the passed in val
    flag(this, 'message', msg);
  }
```

All `exist` then does, is get this value through the `flag` `util` and evaluates if it not equals to `null`, using the `assert` method defined on the `Assertion prototype`.

```
  Assertion.addProperty('exist', function () {
    this.assert(
        null != flag(this, 'object')
      , 'expected #{this} to exist'
      , 'expected #{this} to not exist'
    );
  });
```

Comment: But how does it stop the remaining code after the expect call from executing if the test fails?  For example, if there is a `done()` callback later in the `it`, it's not executed...

Answer (score 3):

When you call `expect(foo)`, a new Assertion object is instantiated.

to, have, with, and similar properties do nothing but to return that Assertion instance. They are only for readability.

However, in your example, *exists*, is actually something that runs an assertion.

Its a property. They way properties are added to Assertion is that they are defined as getter functions as you can [see here.](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js#L37)

`expect(foo).to.exist` could be broken down to this:

```
const assertion = new Assertion;
assertion.exists;
```

`assertion.exists` is added to the assertion object with a getter.
That means when you execute assertion.exists, to evaluate the value of assertion.exists, a function that was earlier provided to `addProperty` is executed.

You can read more about [getter functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).